# Why $\int_{\mathbb R/\mathbb Z}f(x)dx=\int_0^1 f(x)dx$ if $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is $1-$periodic?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ a function that is one periodic. Why $$\int_{\mathbb R/\mathbb Z}f(x)dx=\int_0^1f(x)dx \ \ ?$$

My ideas :

$\mathbb R/\mathbb Z=\{e^{2i\pi t}\mid t\in [0,1)\}$,

1) so $$\int_{\mathbb R/\mathbb Z}f(x)dx=\int_0^1 f(e^{2i\pi t})2i\pi e^{2 i\pi t}dt,$$
but it doesn'm make sense since $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$.

2) There is a function $F:\mathbb C\to \mathbb R$ s.t. $f(\theta )=F(e^{2i\pi t})$ (btw is this function $F$ unique ?), and thus $$\int_{\mathbb R/\mathbb Z}f(x)dx=\int_C F(z)dz=\int_0^1F(e^{2i\pi t})2i\pi e^{2i\pi t}dt=\int_0^1 f(t)2i\pi e^{2i\pi t}dt.$$
It's better that $1)$ but I still have this $2i\pi e^{2i\pi t}$ in the integral...

3) Still using $F$ defined previously : $$\int_0^1 f(t)dt=\int_0^1 F(e^{2i\pi t})dt=\int_{\mathbb R/\mathbb Z}\frac{F(z)}{iz}dz;$$

So at the end, I don't really get the intuition.

Comment: You should take $\int_{\mathbb R/\mathbb Z}f(x)dx=\int_0^1f(x)dx$ as the definition of the LHS. That integral is shift invariant so it comes from the Haar measure on the topological group $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$. You can identify $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ with the unit circle $S^1=\{e^{2i\pi x}\mid x\in [0,1)\}$ because $x \mapsto e^{2i \pi x}$ is an homeomorphism between the two, but then you need to define what it means integrating on $S^1$. And don't confuse the function on $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ with that on $S^1$

Comment: @reuns: Thanks for your very helpful comment :) It looks like I mix things a bit, and your comment clarify things better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} = \{e^{2\pi it}\mid t\in [0,1)\}$

No, it isn't. That's a way to map $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ to a circle. It isn't the quotient $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ itself.

The quotient space is, by definition, the set of cosets $\{a+\mathbb{Z}\mid a\in\mathbb{R}\}$. What structure can we apply to this quotient, inherited from $\mathbb{R}$? Addition works, since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a normal subgroup with respect to addition. Multiplication doesn't, since $\mathbb{Z}$ isn't an ideal. Topology works; we define a set in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ to be open or closed if its preimage in $\mathbb{R}$ is. Order doesn't work, since we loop around; every coset contains elements both smaller and larger than any particular real number.

What about measure? We're trying to integrate something, so we need a measure on $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. We could try directly inheriting the measure by setting $\mu(S+\mathbb{Z})$ in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ to be the measure of that set in $\mathbb{R}$ - but this leads to a measure that's either zero or $\infty$ everywhere. Instead, we take a look - is there any particularly nice system of representatives? Yes, there is - the half-open interval $[0,1)$. Define the measure of a set $S+\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ to be the measure of $(S+\mathbb{Z})\cap [0,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

And then, the formula we want falls right out. $\int_{\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}}f = \int_0^1 f$ by the definition of the measure on $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Now, that may have seemed like an arbitrary choice - but there are good reasons for it to be standard. Consider the theorem of [Haar measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure); on a nice enough topological group, there's a translation-invariant measure, finite on compact sets, unique up to constant multiples. For compact groups such as this one, there's a standard way to choose that constant multiple: the measure of the whole group should be $1$. And that's exactly what we have - the unique translation-invariant measure such that $\mu(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})=1$.

Comment: Nice answer :) I'll let you know if I need some clarification,